# Prime NG dynamic table column definitions

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-table

I have the following column definition for a primeNg table:

```
this.cols = [
      { field: 'cli_nombres', header: 'Nombre', type: 'text' },
      { field: 'cli_apellidos', header: 'Apellido', type: 'text' },
      { field: 'cli_email', header: 'Email', type: 'email' },
      { field: 'cli_nro_documento', header: 'DNI', type: 'number' },
      { field: 'cli_fecha_nacimiento', header: 'Fecha de Nacimiento', type: 'date' },
      { field: 'id_pri_provincias', header: 'Provincia', type: 'text' },
      { field: 'id_pri_localidades', header: 'Localidad', type: 'text' },
      { field: 'cli_direccion_nombre', header: 'Direccion', type: 'text' },
      { field: 'cli_direccion_nro', header: 'Altura', type: 'number' },
      { field: 'cli_cp', header: 'Codigo Postal', type: 'text' },
];
```

And it is being shown all the data so far:

```
<!-- Columnas -->
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="clients">
          <tr pEditableRow>
              <td>
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
              </td>
              <td *ngFor="let col of cols" [pEditableColumn]="rowData[col.field]" pEditableColumnField="{{col.field}}">
                <p-cellEditor>
                  <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                    <input #cellInput pInputText [type]="col.type" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]"
                          (keydown.enter)="afterCellUpdate(rowData); cellInput.blur();"
                          (keydown)="onArrowKeyDown($event)"
                          (focus)="onCellEditFocus(rowData)"
                          (blur)="afterCellUpdate(rowData); onCellEditBlur($event)"
                          />
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                    {{ rowData[col.field] }}
                  </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
```

Situation is that this two fields shows the id and i want instead to show the field with the name of the column. This are the ones in particular.

```
 { field: 'id_pri_provincias', header: 'Provincia', type: 'text' },
 { field: 'id_pri_localidades', header: 'Localidad', type: 'text' },
```

Do you know what is the equivalent in primeNG to the valueGetter from nggrid? That would help me to be able to display the name of the province instead of the id param.

Or if you happen to know a different solution it is most welcomed.

I'm expecting that the columns show the value name instead of the id value.

I tried adding an field called template in here:

```
{ field: 'id_pri_provincias', header: 'Provincia', type: 'text', template: provinciaTemplate },
```

```
 getProvinciaNombre(id: number): string {
    const provincia = this.provincias.find(prov => prov.id_pri_provincias === id);
    console.log(provincia)
    return provincia ? provincia.pro_nombre : '';
  }
```

```
 provinciaTemplate(rowData: any) {
    return this.getProvinciaNombre(rowData.id_pri_provincias);
  }
```

But primeNG does not recognize template as a property.